# Calendar- Date issue when using web service soap with java

Tags: java, web-services, date, soap, calendar

When I get an object via web service with java and after editing some fields of it, when I want to save it back with the corresponding web service method I get problems with the format of the Date fields.

The api of the web service, which I cannot modify, uses the class Java - Calendar for the corresponding fields with Dates.
The accepted format of the dateTime in the xml is: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss like

```
<Generated>2017-03-21T10:22:55</Generated>
```

But after updating some data and try to save it I get the following error:

```
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client
faultSubcode: 
faultString: Invalid property (E3010)
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
{}:null
```

And in the soap response something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Invalid property (E3010)</faultstring>
        <faultactor/>
        <detail>Property (of type 'dateTime') has badly formatted value '2017-03-21T10:22:55.000Z'. Data path: SaveRequest->Generated</detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to remove the milliseconds and the 'Z' from the value.

I tried something like:

```
Calendar calendar = object.getGenerated();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String formatted = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
calendar = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(formatted);
```

But it is not working as the Calendar class is setting anyway the milliseconds and the 'Z' in the property for the web service.

Any idea how this can be solved? I mean remove the milliseconds and the 'Z' from the Calendar property?